# ТГ бот, загрузчик не может отправить видео

Tags: python, aiogram, pytube

```
import os
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor
from pytube import YouTube
import config

bot = Bot(config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def result(message: types.Message):
        link = message.text
        yt = YouTube(link)
        await message.answer(f"Title: {yt.title}\nViews: {yt.views}")
        yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download("FileVideos")
        
        file_path = r'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/DownloaderVideo/FileVideos/' + f'{yt.title}.mp4'


        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
                text = file.read(file)
                await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, text)

        os.remove()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Этот код сохраняет видео у себя потом пытаеться отправить пользователю но не получаеться выводить такую ошибку:

```
...
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DownloaderVideo\main.py", line 19, in result
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
  'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/DownloaderVideo/FileVideos/The items gone... There is nothing we can
do....mp4'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все же, лучше попытаться на более простом варианте (без использования бота и ютуба), а поработать именно над открытием. Я написал новый код именно к этой части, и у меня заработало и ошибка не появилась

```
file_path = r'C:/Users/Admin/Videos/Movavi Screen Recorder/p1.mkv'

with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
    text = file.read()
    print(text)
```

Вероятно, проблема из-за того, что python сохранил файл под другим именем или не сохранил вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Там же написно

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Такого файла нет или он не найден.
Измени название например на "video1.mp4", питон не любит тучу точек

Comment: Выбирайте выражения, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Я тут хорошо подумал и заменил:

```
file_path = r'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/DownloaderVideo/FileVideos/' + f'{yt.title}.mp4'


        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
                text = file.read(file)
                await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, text)

        os.remove()
```

На это:

```
video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, types.InputFile(video))
os.remove(video)
```